# amarok displays wrong time for ogg files

Tags: fedora, ogg, amarok

I am running Amarok 2.5.0 on Fedora 16 and it is displaying the wrong time (zero or a very large number) instead of the actual duration of the song, for all ogg audio files. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "displaying the wrong time"? Against what "right time" are you comparing?

Comment: @vonbrand Meaning the it either shows 0 or a very large number, but not the actual times. Yes I'm comparing against the real/actual duration of the song.